# Populate a dropdownlist with objectdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist with an objectdatasource programatically. It's a user control, so in my  ascx I have this:

```
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsFicheros" runat="server" 
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                        onselecting="odsFicheros_Selecting" SelectMethod="ejecutaconsultaFicheros" TypeName="DatosGW.ControlBuscador">

    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

     <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbFicheros" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
                         DataTextField="fichero" DataValueField="fichero" DataSourceID="odsFicheros" 
                        ondatabound="cmbFicheros_DataBound" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="cmbFicheros_SelectedIndexChanged">
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

On the code behind I do this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {



    odsFicheros.TypeName = "DatosGW.ControlBuscador";
    odsFicheros.SelectMethod = "ejecutaconsultaFicheros";
    Parameter consultas = new Parameter(consulta, TypeCode.String);
    odsFicheros.SelectParameters.Add(consultas);
    odsFicheros.DataBind();

    cmbFicheros.DataSource = odsFicheros;

    this.ejecutarConsulta();
}
```

And finally on my ControlBuscador class I have the method which returns a datatable, but it doesn't work, why?. If you need more details, please let me know it.

Comment: Are you calling cmbFicheros.DataBind() at any point?  You may also need to set its DataTextField and DataValueField, if you're not doing so elsewhere.

Comment: If I do it I have this: Both DataSource are DataSourceID are defined in 'cmbFicheros'. Remove one definition.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have it set in your ascx.  Not used to seeing that in programmatic approaches, so I skimmed right past it.  What happens if you remove the DataSourceID="odsFicheros" from your ascx, and DataBind in the codebehind?

Comment: I did it and nothing. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, I did this with the wizard on the Selectin property:

```
 e.InputParameters["consulta"] = hfConsulta.Value;
```

I created a HiddenField with the parameter I want, so now it's working